# Create new folder for new sender name and move message into new folder

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2010

## Background

I'd like to have Outlook 2010 automatically [move](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_sender_rule.htm) e-mails into folders designated by the person's name. For example:

1. Click Rules
2. Click Manage Rules & Alerts
3. Click New Rule
4. Select "Move messages from someone to a folder"
5. Click Next

The following dialog is shown:

[image: Rules Wizard]

## Problem

The next part usually looks as follows:

1. Click `people or public group`
2. Select the desired person
3. Click `specified`
4. Select the desired folder

## Question

How would you automate those problematic manual tasks? Here's the logic for the new rule I'd like to create:

1. Receive a new message.
2. Extract the name of the sender.
3. If it does not exist, create a new folder under Inbox
4. Move the new message into the folder assigned to that person's name

I think this will require a VBA macro.

## Related Links

- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/A_420-Extending-Outlook-Rules-via-Scripting.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814735.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook
- http://en.kioskea.net/faq/6174-outlook-a-macro-to-create-folders
- http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/02/25/outlook-macros-part-1-moving-emails-into-personal-folders.aspx

## Update #1

The code might resemble something like:

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_NewMail()
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set myInbox = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set mySenderName = myItem.SenderName

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set myDestinationFolder = myInbox.Folders.Add(mySenderName, olFolderInbox)

    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = " & mySenderName)
    myItem.Move myDestinationFolder

ErrorHandler:
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

## Update #2

Split the code as follows:

[image: VBA Editing]

Sent a test message and nothing happened. The instructions for actually triggering a message when a new message arrives are a little light on details (for example, no mention is made regarding `ThisOutlookSession` and how to use it).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This often asked question is answered here.

https://web.archive.org/web/20131024034054/http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/automatically-triage-emails-by-sender-name/

Uses ItemAdd to do what Newmail, now NewMailEx, would do.

In the ThisOutlookSesion module

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
 
  ' set object reference to default Inbox
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)
 
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim senderName As String
 
  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(item) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit
 
  Set Msg = item
 
  ' move received email to target folder based on sender name
  senderName = Msg.senderName
 
  If CheckForFolder(senderName) = False Then  ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(senderName)
  Else
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = _
    objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(senderName)
  End If
 
  Msg.Move targetFolder
 
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Function CheckForFolder(strFolder As String) As Boolean
' looks for subfolder of specified folder, returns TRUE if folder exists.
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 
' try to set an object reference to specified folder
On Error Resume Next
Set FolderToCheck = olInbox.Folders(strFolder)
On Error Goto 0
 
If Not FolderTocheck Is Nothing Then
  CheckForFolder = True
End If
 
ExitProc:
Set FolderToCheck = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function

Function CreateSubFolder(strFolder As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
' assumes folder doesn't exist, so only call if calling sub knows that
' the folder doesn't exist; returns a folder object to calling sub
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 
Set CreateSubFolder = olInbox.Folders.Add(strFolder)
 
ExitProc:
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Do I have to somehow enable it or does it just work?

Comment: If you have never used VBA before look up how to change security settings.

Answer (score 3):

I'd forget using rules completely and instead make a VBA macro that's attached to the [NewMail event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171307(v=office.11).aspx) that will create a folder (using the [Folders.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220308(v=office.12).aspx)) based on the [SenderName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171985(v=office.11).aspx), and then move it there with the MailItem's [Move method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220127(v=office.11).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. If only it were that simple. The instructions for creating a new mail event are not wholly comprehensive (e.g., the instructions assume knowledge of how to use `ThisOutlookSession`).